# How can I prove this Vector space is sum of two space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ s.t.  $T^2=0$
Show that $$\dim V=\dim\left(\ker T+\ker T^{(t)}\right)$$
$t$ is transpose.
Field is Real number

Is is true?

Comment: Do you mean $\dim V = \dim\ker T+\dim\ker T^t$? Are yo aware that $0^t=0$?

Comment: No. I mean dimension of sum

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Note that if the equation was as you wrote in the comment then $T=0$ would be a counterexample

Comment: Is the matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio - Right, so the dimension of both elements in the sum would be $dim(V)$ and this would give us $2dim(V)$ which is twice as much as the RHS

Comment: @Belgi It's not a matrix, it's a linear transformation. It doesn't matter where it is over because any two $n$-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic, so you can take matrices over it most pleases you.

Comment: @DonAntonio - My bad, I meant the vector space

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - this example seem to check out..

Comment: But $\ker T^t\subseteq V^*\ne V$, isn't it? Also, even if we pick a basis and identify $V$ with $V^*$ (in other words, consider $T$ and $T^t$ as matrices), what about the case $T=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - that it does satisfy the proposed equality..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - If $B=\{e_{i}\}_{i=1}^{3}$ is the standard base then $Ker(T)=sp\{e_{1},e_{2}\}$and
$Ker(T^{t})=sp\{e_{2},e_{3}\}$ so the sum is $sp\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\}$
and so both RHS and LHS equal to $3$

Comment: @Belgi : I understood my mistake... Thank you :)

Comment: @Belgi Ah, I was looking wrong way it seems

Comment: In characteristic 2, the 2x2 matrix with all entries equal to 1 is a counterexample.

Comment: @bartogian ohoh... field is Real number...

Comment: Maybe this is addressed in the comments and I just can't see it, but is $T^{(t)}$ well-defined if $T$ is a linear operator, rather than a matrix representing that linear operator with respect to a certain basis? Or maybe it isn't, but $\ker T^{(t)}$ is?

Comment: Can someone explain me what $T^t$ mean here ? Is it $T^t: V\rightarrow V^{*}$ such that for all $l\in V^*,\quad V^t=l\circ V$ ? Thanks

Comment: T be a square matrix or linear operator. T^t is just transpose matrix.

Comment: @user122794 The defition of the transpose of an endomorphism is exactly what I said in my previous comment..

Answer (score 1):

Take $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ with $(\cdot,\cdot)$ the usual inner product. Then a coordinate-free description of the transpose is $(Tv,w)=(v,T^t w)$.

For a subspace W of V, we let $W^\perp=\{v\in V\mid (v,w)=0\  \forall\  w\in W\}$.  Then $V=W+W^\perp$ (actually a direct sum, but we don't need that). This is the point in the proof where we use the fact that the ground field is $\mathbb{R}$.

So it suffices to show that $(\ker T)^\perp\subset \ker(T^t)$.

Suppose $w\in (\ker T)^\perp$ and $v\in V$. Then $(v,T^t w)=(Tv,w)$. Since $T^2=0$, $Tv\in \ker T$ and therefore $(Tv,w)=0$. Thus we've shown that $(v,T^t w)=0$ for all $v$ and hence $T^tw=0$, implying $w\in \ker(T^t)$, as required.